# Changing String date format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

my current date format is : 
08/11/2008 00:00

I need to convert this output to 
2008/11/08 00:00
However, using the SimpleDateFormat as researched it is unable to do so and give me a totally different output, here are my codes as Follows :

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
Date starting= simpleDateFormat2.parse(startTime);
System.out.println("" + simpleDateFormat2.format(starting) + " real date " + startTime);
```

i do know that i am parsing in the right string given that the following output occurs :

```
0014/05/01 00:00 real date 08/11/2008 00:00
```

i am not too sure about how as to the mechanics detected  0014/05/01 00:00 instead of

2008/11/08 00:00

i look forward to all sugguestions 
Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks guys! for the suggestions!!@madprogrammer  yes this truly works ! another thing i found out too is the use of .setLenient to false but yours works betters

Answer (score 13):

The first thing you need to do is parse the original value to a `Date` object

```
String startTime = "08/11/2008 00:00";
// This could be MM/dd/yyyy, you original value is ambiguous 
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
Date dateValue = input.parse(startTime);
```

Once you have that done, you can format the `dateValue` any way you want...

```
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
System.out.println("" + output.format(dateValue) + " real date " + startTime);
```

which outputs:

```
2008/11/08 00:00 real date 08/11/2008 00:00
```

The reason you're getting `0014/05/01 00:00` is `SimpleDateFormat` (when using `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm`) is using `08` for the year, `11` for the month and `2008` for the day, it's doing an internal rolling of the values to correct the values to a valid date

Answer (score 5):

I should like to contribute the modern answer.

```
    DateTimeFormatter currentFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm");
    DateTimeFormatter convertedOutputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm");
    String startTime = "08/11/2008 00:00";
    LocalDateTime starting = LocalDateTime.parse(startTime, currentFormatter);
    System.out.println(starting.format(convertedOutputFormatter));
```

This prints

```
2008/11/08 00:00
```

The `SimpleDateFormat` class you tried to use is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. You have experienced but a little of the trouble with it. Instead I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

As others have said, you need to use two formatters, one for specifying your current format and one for specifying the desired format.

### What went wrong in your code?

Your formatter with format pattern `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm` interpreted 08/11/2008 as the 2008th day of the 11th month of year 8 of the common era. It doesn’t disturb a `SimpleDateFormat` with default settings that there are only 30 days in November, it just continues counting into the following months and years, ending up on a date five and a half years later (2008 divided by 365.25 is very close to 5.5).

### Question: Can I use `java.time` with my Java version?

If using at least **Java 6**, you can.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On (older) Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Answer (score 4):

It is because the source date string you parsed is in a **different** format than your SimpleDateFormatter. Your source is in `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` format. Change the string in the SimpleDateFormat to `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`.

Try using another format after your first format.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
//You gotta parse it to a Date before correcting it
Date parsedDate = simpleDateFormat2.parse(startTime);
simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
String newFormatttedDate = simpleDateFormat2.format(parsedDate);
```

Comment: I like how your reputation said 365 :)

Comment: Yeah,like a year..just noticed it.thanks for pointing it out..ahha

Comment: Or `dd/MM/yyyyy HH:mm`, the actual `String` value is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing the date `08/11/2008 00:00` with the format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm` but this date **is not** in this format.