# How to Change the date format to yyyy.mm.dd through user defined java expression in Pentaho 8 CE?

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, date-formatting, pentaho-data-integration

How to Change the date format yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss to yyyy.mm.dd through user defined java expression in Pentaho 8 CE?

Note that question refers to USER DEFINED JAVA EXPRESSIONS in Pentaho 8 CE and not to plain Java.

Input field containing the date is of type `Date`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing String date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846358/changing-string-date-format)

Comment: The possible duplicate mentioned refers to Java, and not to User Defined Java Expressions in Pentaho 8 CE, which is the subject of the question.

Comment: Possibly run kettle with locale setting conform provided format ? -Dlocale="needed"

Comment: In step "user defined java expression" is better to operate with java.util.Date (LocalDate).