# How to convert "2019-04-11T05:00:54.000+01:00" into dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm format

Tags: java, date, time, format

I am not able to convert `XMLGregorianCalendar` dateTime into format `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm`.

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

     XMLGregorianCalendar Datetime ="2019-04-11T05:00:54.000+01:00";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");


      String requiredDate = formatter.format(Datetime);

     System.out.println("requiredDate" + requiredDate);

 }
}
```

I am getting an error as----

```
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to XMLGregorianCalendar
     XMLGregorianCalendar Datetime ="2019-04-11T05:00:54.000+01:00";
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/835963/9472892). It might be helpful for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.Date to XMLGregorianCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835889/java-util-date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar)

Comment: Do you just want to convert a date String from one format to the other? If so, you don't have to use `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Isn’t this just a duplicate of [Changing String date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846358/changing-string-date-format) (and many other similar questions)?

Comment: how the above thing can be done using Javascript ??

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter requiredFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                    .withLocale(Locale.FRENCH);

    String originalDateTimeString = "2019-04-11T05:00:54.000+01:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(originalDateTimeString);
    String requiredDate = dateTime.format(requiredFormatter);
    System.out.println("requiredDate: " + requiredDate);
```

Output from this snippet is (on Java 9.0.4):

> requiredDate: 11/04/2019 05:00

Use Java’s built-in localized date and time formats. Don’t bother with rolling your own formatter through a format pattern string. In most cases Java knows better what your audience expects, writing a format pattern string is error-prone, and code using a built-in format lends itself better to porting to a different locale. I don’t know whether your desired locale is French, of course, since many other locales fit the format you asked for, `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm`, too. Just pick the locale that is right for your situation.

The date/time classes you tried to use, `XMLGregorianCalendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are old now, and the latter notoriously troublesome, so you shouldn’t use those if you can avoid it (which you can). Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### What went wrong in your code?

- Minor point, variable names in Java begin with a small letter, so your variable should be called `dateTime` or `datetime`.
- You cannot assign a string (like `"2019-04-11T05:00:54.000+01:00"`) to a variable of type `XMLGregorianCalendar`. This is what your error message is trying to tell you. The correct way to convert would have been the one already shown in zmr’s answer:

  ```
     XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
             .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2019-04-11T05:00:54.000+01:00");
  ```
- A `SimpleDateFormat` cannot format an `XMLGregorianCalendar`. The code compiles, but at runtime you get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date`.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign dateTimeStamp to XMLGregorianCalendar which is abstract class.

You can achieve the result by using below code snippet :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    XMLGregorianCalendar datetime = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2019-04-11T05:00:54.000+01:00");

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

    String requiredDate = formatter.format(datetime.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());

    System.out.println("requiredDate" + requiredDate);
}
```